# Dependency injection with spring - Use beans between multiple maven modules

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm kind of new to spring and maven - anyway I did some research and did not find anything helpful to my question.

Currently I am working on a maven project with multiple modules where each module has its own concern. 
Like this:

```
Parent
  - Consuming Rest Service
  - Load balancing
  - Distributing jobs with RabbitMQ
```

It's not as important what I am actually doing.

I finished writing the unit tests and the source for the module consuming the rest service. Yet I did not yet set up the dependency injection. 
For example my RestService wrapper has a Facade Api and a setter ApiConnection which I set in the constructor all time. 
Now I would like to move to dependency injection, but I only found example using an own

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

method, which is not really suitable for me (as my Api wrapper will only get used by other projects, but not run stand alone).

Can anyone give me some pointers how I can set up this maven module on its own and then later set up the whole project without copying all the files together?

Thanks in advance, 
Olli

Comment: Actually it's hard to understand what you are truing to achieve. If you need some services available in all the modules create a new module `core` and place the services in the module. Then just make all existing modules depend on the `core`.

Comment: I think you're making this too complicated.  If you want to share beans, put them in a common JAR and add it as a Maven dependency in every project that needs them.